# Optimize the GUID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, guid

Sorry for my English; in our SQL Server 2014 project, we have two tables that are synchronized between a web application and Android devices (they are therefore on all mobiles).

In our databases, these two tables are identified by unique identifiers of type `integer` as the primary key, but we also wanted a `GUID` single column that  "follows" the data from its creation.

Our table A has these columns:

```
A_ID int
A_guid nvarchar (50)
```

And DetailA table:

```
detailA_ID int
detailA_guid nvarchar (50)
A_guid nvarchar (50) (on mobile only)
```

GUID columns are used in mobile applications and in synchronization on the SQL server, the "detail" data will look for the SQL Server ID corresponding to "A_guid":

```
select A_ID 
from A 
where A_guid = detailA.A_guid
```

All our data has been linked between them via SQL Server credentials. Of course everything works as long as the data is few. "GUID" will soon take a little time. All our GUID columns are in the format:

```
DEVICE_ID-YYYMMDD- [Function NEWID ()]
```

Apply an index is not very effective. I thought about changing the format to correspond to :

```
DEVICE_ID-YYYMMDD_HIS
```

But I do not know if we will gain speed.

Comment: Speed for what?

Comment: Have you read this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803326/use-of-non-clustered-index-on-guid-type-column-in-sql-server

Comment: If you are storing GUIDs why are you using varchar(50)? You should be using uniqueidentifier.

Comment: A GUID is already globally unique (as per the name); adding a device ID and a date doesn't gain you anything.  You'd be better off splitting this up into separate columns (with, per Sean, `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` for the GUID) and then you can index those columns. You can use a computed column if you need a single string representation of that value, but you shouldn't really need it. If you have a way of actually generating an increasing unique value per device (like the time stamp accurate to a millisecond, for example) that value would index better than a GUID, so you might not need it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my mates said, if you want to use GUID, then use `uniqueidentifier` which is a known datatype in SQL Server.

If GUID is not enough for your requirement, but you need to involve more information with it. I would suggest to create an informal table that will hold all required information in separate columns with the correspond GUID. This is better than concreting the GUID in a string with other values.

So rather than doing : `DEVICE_ID-YYYMMDD- [Function NEWID ()]`

You'll be better doing this : `INSERT INTO informationTable (DeviceId, CreatedDate, RecordGUID)`

Answer (score 0):

As a GUID (Globally Unique Identifiter) is, by definition, unique, you should not need to include `DEVICE_ID` in the guid columns. If you need that data, store it separately in its own column. This, as mentioned in the comments, will allow you to use the `uniqueidentifier` datatype, which will improve performance a bit. Definitely, build an index on the guid column, it will be much faster than no index!

(I’m not sure what `_HIS` refers to, but adding extra characters is not going to make things faster.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The DEVICE_ID is used to know the device which has created data. In project all GUID has generated by the same format. We thought that the format which use _HIS (hour, minute, second) would be speeder because it was only number (with this we wouldn't use SQL Server NEWID function anymore but a custom one).